# What should I do about Firefox and snap after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: upgrade, firefox, 22.04, snap

I upgraded ubuntu from 20 to 22 LTS. Along the process, there appeared some pop-ups indicating something about Firefox and snap. In one of them I think it was mentioned a deadline of 7 days to remove one or both of them. So my questions are, what do these messages exactly say, and also what should I do about Firefox and/or snap in my upgraded Ubuntu.

Comment: What do you want to do about them?  You can run just the snap version, or you can do the non-snap (deb) version by following https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22 as the snap version will override the non-snap version.

Comment: Danger of opinion based responses. Leave snap in place but if you wish (as I have done) remove FF as a snap and replace as the APT version as indicated by Terrance with some clear benefits according to your preference.

Comment: I'm not sure what your messages said, but I removed all snap packages following this guide to install Firefox from a ppa: https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/29073